# Magento Custom Option If Statement

Tags: php, magento

I a sorry for the poor question but I have no idea where to start.

Basically I have a product template that utilises 15 custom options for Name, 15 for Tshirt size and 15 for tshirt number.

Using jquery the options are hidden on the personalisation based on the product quantity. It then puts a default * or none for the size.

The only problem is that if a customer orders say 3 tshirts in the emails and customer orders they will see a long list of options that they have not selected.

I was wondering if there was a way to exclufe the option if it equaled * or none.

[image]

SOLVED WITH THE BELOW

```
    <?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array('None','*');
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo $option['label'];
} 
?>

<?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array('None','*');
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value'])));
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

You'll have to modify the template of the email.

The base one is here :

magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\

This is the one for orders, don't forget about invoice, shipment and creditmemo.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItemOptions() as $option): ?>
        <dt><strong><em><?php echo $option['label'] ?></em></strong></dt>
        <dd style="margin:0; padding:0 0 0 9px;">
            <?php echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value']))) ?>
        </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

just add a control on the `$option['value']` or `$option['print_value']`

Maybe also the Pdf function to have the same behaviour on the pdfs will need modifications

Of course as it's native core function, don't modify directly the code but create your module to extends and replace it.

Comment: How would I add a control?? Have you got an example of the syntax

Comment: I just need an IF statement is the option value = "No" or "*" then ignore

Comment: Tried something like this with no joy. 
`$optionvalue = $option['print_value'];
$os = array("*", "None");
if (!in_array($optionvalue, $os)) {
    (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value'])));
}`

Comment: `<?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array(None,*);
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo $option['label'];
} 
?>

<?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array(None,*);
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value'])));
} 
?>
`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using an array and if statement and with dagfr's pointer to the location of the function. Have updated the PDF functions as well as emails and on screen on the carso looks pretty tidy now.

```
       <?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array('None','*');
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo $option['label'];
} 
?>

<?php
$optionvalue = $option['value'];
$array = array('None','*');
if(!in_array($optionvalue,$array)){
     echo (isset($option['print_value']) ? $option['print_value'] : nl2br($this->escapeHtml($option['value'])));
} 
?>
```